# How to initialize already defined flexible length array in C?

Tags: arrays, c

Consider the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int b[];

int main() {
    b = { 4, 5, 6 };
    return 0;
}
```

This of course is illegal.

```
main.c:7:9: error: expected expression before '{' token
    7 |     b = { 4, 5, 6 };
      |         ^
```

I need to initialize array `b` in a function. How to do that?

I know one way, but it's... IDK, really?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int b[3];

int main() {
    b[0] = 4;
    b[1] = 5;
    b[2] = 6;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it the only way of doing that?

**EDIT:**
It's very hard to explain my intent.

Let's say I define items in code. Right? Is that clear? In code, means - it's static, not dynamic. Not runtime. Not "variable length". Let's say it will be 5 items, right? So why don't I just say 5 and set the fixed length to 5?

The reason for this is, I don't have to write:

````c
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```c
but instead I can write
```c
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
````

That saves me the redundant step of counting my items manually, because the compiler counts the items for me. It also allocates the memory on stack for them for me. No need to call `malloc`.

And here goes the hard to explain part:

1. Imagine instead of 1, 2, 3, 4 I have structures. They are not numbered, they contain various data types.
2. Imagine, that later in time I add an additional item to my array, because it will become necessary at a certain point of the project development. To be absolutely clear: this is not by any means dynamic. I will never need a single item more during the runtime. It will be added to the code and committed to Git. And it will stay there, maybe to the end of the program's life.
3. Imagine I add the item, but I forget to update the items count. It's a super common bug.
4. The whole point for me is to learn, whether a syntax in C exists allowing to omit the item count by initializing array inside a function. Now I suspect - it is not possible. I can either make such initialization when defining a variable, but not when assigning to the variable, even if it's the only assignment made to that variable.
5. I'd avoid to allocate more bytes than necessary, also performing more operations than necessary because it's for embedded and I really aim to cut that kind of costs. I also learn how to do the things the correct way, even if I technically could waste some resources.

Additional problem with my real code is some data for the items is not available before a function is called.

So my temporary solution is just to specify the array length. And then remember to update it when I add or remove items DURING DEVELOPMENT. That should work. If it's the correct way of doing that, than it's fine and I'm done. If not, I'd be happy to learn how to do it a better way.

Comment: You could have a struct with flexible array member and `malloc` sufficent space for memory management – or you have a global pointer and let it point to a VLA on the stack (within main) – though I personally tend to considering VLA being a big mistake in the standard and rather tend to avoid them for that reason... If you have a safe upper bound how many elements might reside in (well, quite a bit less than `SIZE_MAX`, of course...) you might provide an array of that size and remember separately how many of are actually in use.

Comment: To begin with, "flexible" arrays are only allowed as the last member of a structure, nowhere else. To continue, it's just not possible to assign to an array directly, only copy to it.

Comment: Is your problem only that you can't use the brace-syntax for the delayed "initialization" or is the size of the array in the definition somehow a problem? You mention something in the title that is probably meant to refer to VLAs (variable-length arrays), but in your working example there is no such VLA.

Comment: The issue here is, that the compiler doesn't know the size of your array at the time of declaration (`int b[]`), because you are lacking the initialization, so the compiler doesn't know how much memory to reserve. (It's smart, but not THAT smart). I think the best way to go would be a dynamic allocation (malloc/free) with a va_arg function.

Comment: The size is fixed. However, it should be determined by the number of items I add IN THE CODE (not at runtime). Do I have to count my elements manually after adding and then put the sum as the array size? It seems weird to do that for the compiler. The compiler KNOWS how many items I added. However, in the runtime the items content will be defined. So some code will do like `item1 = ...`, and then my code will place that item into the array. The code has the number of items known.

Comment: @Eric - Already deleted.  Thanks.  But when I attempt `int b[]; int b[3];`, I get two errors,  _error: definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer_ and 
_error: redefinition of 'b'_

Comment: "_by the number of items I add IN THE CODE_": I don't think you can find a good definition for how to determine this number. Because this is a global variable, there could be multiple functions with `b = { 4, 5, 6 };` or `b[0] = 4;` statements, also throughout different translation units, and it is also impossible to determine which of these will actually be executed at runtime. So there isn't really a sensible way of deducing the supposed size of `b` from such statements, but because `b` is a global, its size must be known at compile-time.

Comment: @ryyker You may be compiling as C++. C++ doesn't have tentative definitions.

Comment: @user17732522 - No, I am not.   I am compiling with a C99 compiler.  Although I have seen a few other places where this compiler is non-compliant, and very well could be on this point as well.

Comment: Variable-length arrays make the most sense when used as local variables. In your case you wish to expose one at file scope, but initialize it at a local scope. That doesn't make much sense - in case you need to do something like that you should probably use malloc instead. Using global variables is already bad practice, so any discussion about "what's best" has already been thrown out the window. It might be more constructive to focus on the actual problem you need to solve with these arrays.

Comment: @ryyker it probably is non-compliant, https://godbolt.org/z/rjhrddGP8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Imagine I add the item, but I forget to update the items count.*

I think what you're getting at is that you need the size of the array, but you don't want to hardcode it.

No problem. Use this:

```c
int a[] = { 5, 6, 7 };

size_t n = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
```

Then you can do stuff like this:

```c
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n ; ++i )
   do_this( a[i] );
```

or

```c
do_that( a, n );
```

At no point was `3` mentioned, so the code keep working even if you change the initialization of `a` to the following:

```c
int a[] = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
```

---

> *The whole point for me is to learn, whether a syntax in C exists allowing to omit the item count by initializing array inside a function*

There's nothing special about arrays in functions. Just like outside of functions, you will need to provide a size (`int b[...];`) or an initializer (`int b[] = ...;`). Without this, the program wouldn't know how much space to allocate.

But while you say this is the point, it's obviously not. You appear to want to ensure that two arrays are the same size, as you make clear in your following paragraph.

---

> *I'd avoid to allocate more bytes than necessary, also performing more operations than necessary because it's for embedded and I really aim to cut that kind of costs. I also learn how to do the things the correct way, even if I technically could waste some resources.*

If the array fits on the stack, you can use the following to allocate it on the stack instead of using `malloc`.

```c
void do_that( int *a, size_t n ) {
   int b[n];
   ...
}
```

These are called *variable length arrays*, and it was an addition to C99. (They are variable-length in the sense that every instance of an array created by this code can have a different length. But the created arrays are fixed in size like every C array.)

Answer (score 4):

The proper term is *variable length array*. This is an array whose size is determined by a non-constant expression. Its size is set at execution time when program execution reaches the definition of the array. (“Flexible” is used in the term *flexible array member*, which is an array that is the last member of a structure and that adapts to the memory allocated for the structure.)

The size of a variable length array must be given where the array is defined, as with `int b[n];`. You cannot leave the size incomplete, as with `int b[];`, and specify it later.

C has no grammar for assigning directly to an array. You can assign values to individual elements, and a method for specifying values in aggregate is to use `memcpy` to copy them from another array, which can be a compound literal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    int n = 3;
    int b[n];
    memcpy(b, (int []) { 4, 5, 6 }, sizeof b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        printf("b[%d] = %d.\n", i, b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that's wrong is

```c
int b[];
```

This makes no sense. gcc treats this as the following

```c
int b[1];
```

This is most definitely wrong. You want

```c
int *b;
```

Cloning `a` would be done as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t size = sizeof( a );

b = malloc( size );
if ( !b ) {
   perror( "malloc" );
   exit( 1 );
}

memcpy( b, a, size );
```

Don't forget to `free( b );`.

Answer (score 1):

> Imagine I add the item, but I forget to update the items count. It's a super common bug.

The crux of this problem is that you should not code the *items count* as some constant.  Instead use code to calculate to *items count* value or simply use the size of `b[]`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

// Array b exist _someplace_ of some size

void assign_b() {
  // Form the initialization list.
  same_type_as_b_element b_values[] = { 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 };
  // Same size?
  static_assert(sizeof b == sizeof b_values), "Mis-matched sizes in b[]");
  // Copy to b
  memcpy(b, b_values, sizeof b);
}
```